# vue3 websocket not receiving messages sent from postman

Tags: websocket, vuejs3

I have created simple websocket server on node js:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`Received message: ${message}`);
    ws.send(`You sent: ${message}`);
  });
  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection closed');
  });
});

console.log('WebSocket server is running on port 8080');
```

It works fine on postman. Messages are being sent and received.

I'm struggling with catching these messages from vue3 perspective.

```
let socket: WebSocket;
const data = reactive([])

onMounted(() => {
  socket = new WebSocket(
    "ws://localhost:8080/"
  );

  socket.onopen = () => {
    console.log("connected")
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log(event.data);
  };

  socket.onerror = (event) => {
    console.log('Socket error');
    console.log(event);
  };

  socket.onclose = (event) => {
    console.log('Socket closed');
    console.log(event);
  };
});
```

Vue connects to the websocket, but still it does not see messages sent from postman. Appreciate any hint.